# When a orphaned object is deleted, are deletion rules applied?

Tags: core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Let's say I have a class called `Directory` and another called `File`, and they have a one-to-many relationship. (A `Directory` has many `File`s).

In the [restkit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) docs for `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`:

> An NSOperation subclass that sends an HTTP request and performs object mapping on the parsed response body to createNSManagedObject instances, establishes relationships between objects using RKConnectionDescription objects, and cleans up orphaned objects that no longer exist in the remote backend system.

My question is if the deletion rules are applied by RestKit when an orphan object is found and deleted. In this case, would be all `File`s get deleted? (If I use Cascade in deletion rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the deletion rules are part of Core Data, not RestKit so they will be run.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it when I finish my app.